# Operations on repeated index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, indexing

```
    P   d
A   3   2
A   3   3
A   1   1
A   1   1
B   6   9
B   3   9
B   1   9
C   5   1
C   2   1
```

I have scv file that is full of similar data indixed with repeated a , b , c ....... etc , has columns labeled price , data and some other labels, how to calculate the sum of all the numbers in the price column that are indexed with every single index alone , and repeat the process for other all indexes , without knowing all the indexes ?
For example : 
The price of A =8 
The price of C = 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by the index

```
df.groupby(level=0).P.sum()
```